# JTextArea - count selected rows

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm creating a text editor, and I want to count selected lines, as in image below.

This is the interface that I created until now.

[image]

For example if those two lines are selected, I need a way to store number of selected lines (2 in this case) into a variable. Is there a way to do that?

If you need any piece of code to see, I will add.

Comment: that is not close to what I suggested!!! I suggested you subtract the "line numbers", not the starting/ending offsets of the selected text. Where did you modify the method to past in the "offset".

Comment: *"JTextField count selected rows"* A text field only ever has a single line, so it the count of rows that have all or part elected will be either 0 or 1. I expect you actually meant a `JTextArea`, but expectations can be turned into knowledge if a [mcve] is posted. Please post an MCVE in future questiosn.

Comment: @AndrewThompson check title again please, it says "JTextArea", not "JTextField"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `getLineAtCaret()` method found in [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/). This will get the line number at the caret (which won't help here).

So, you will need to modify the code to receive an offset as a parameter. Then you can pass in the `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` values of the text component and use these values to return the line number. Then once you know the line number of each you can subtract the starting line number from the ending line number to give you the number of rows selected.

You can also check out the `Text Component Line Number` blog entry for a line number component to use for you editor.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to implement what you said, and I think I found a way. Please can  you check the EDIT it to see if is right way? Because most of times, I get the right number of lines selected, but sometimes I get wrong value, for example, if I select 4 lines, it says I got 3 or 5 lines selected, but not always.